# Laravel 4 foreach error - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to query some informations with laravel 4 blade syntax but I am always getting this error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

**Controller**

```
<?php

class ProfileController extends BaseController {
    public function user($username) {
        $users = User::where("username", "=", $username);
        if($users->count()) {
            $users = $users->first();
            return View::make("profile.user")->with("users", $users);
        } else {
            return View::make("404");
        }
    }
}
```

**user.blade.php**

```
@extends("layout.main")

@section("content")
    @foreach($users as $user)
        {{$user->id}}
    @endforeach
@stop
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide the error line and mark it in your code here. And btw. the full error also.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object this is the error. I dont understand anything :S

Comment: Laravel and any other framework will give you a line in which that error happens. For example: Trying to get property of non-object in line 42 so you can look up in that line. Also Laravel 4 shows the code block where the error occurs. And if I'm not wrong the line with that error should be highlighted. Sorry but I haven't used Laravel since 6 month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
$users = User::where("username", "=", $username)->get();
```

Also you are using `first` so

```
$users = $users->first();
```

will store only the first user in users variable, so you can't foreach loop it - just remove the line with `first`.

Comment: it is make sense. So what am I suppose to do now? How can I edit my controller codes? (ps: I deleted $users = $users->first(); and codes worked but not in foreach.)

Comment: Did you add `->get();` in users chain?

Comment: What Tom means is that your query only asks for just "1" record. And we all hope that you database or your table won't accept more then one user with the same username. So you restrict your query to get only one username. That means you don't need and you can't loop your result because there is max only one username that match. Otherwise that user don't exist and you database will return 0 or null.

Comment: Now I understand :) You right! I am just get 1 user because of that I just got 1 result :) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its not an object. Try

```
$user['id']; //In this case its an array
```

Other, try to output your $user so you can see whats in it. Is there even data in it?

Comment: I have datas. If I write {{ $users->id }} I am getting data from my DB. Btw your codes worked but I did not get any data. Thank u.

Comment: If my option worked I guess your $users is empty or doens't contain any object/array to work on with foreach. Try: print_r($user); and see if there is anything in user.

Comment: I am getting just "1 1 1" if I write print_r($user). What does it mean?

Comment: @ Chilion I guess you mean "$users"? var_dump($users) to see if there is any "id" or other element you can call with $user->id
@ Baran Sengul I just see you've written that you use {{$users->id}} instead of {{$user->id}}. So which is correct? Is there only one record in your DB?

Comment: Then there is no array in $user. Please try the same with $users, I do think that if you would delete the whole foreach thing and you would try {{$users['id']}} that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you get just the very first row that is (possibly) found

```
$users = $users->first();
```

Then, you pass it to view as `users` variable (wrong naming, why users, if taking just one?)

```
return View::make("profile.user")->with("users", $users);
```

Forget naming right now, here is the problem.
You take !!! one !!! record but you try to itterate it like it is collection of records.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{$user->id}}
@endforeach
```

Since you try to itterate `$users` (which is single user), Laravel will itterate its attributes instead. To solve this, get rid of `@foreach` loop and just print what you need to print -> `{{ $users->id }}` (and rename that variable, please:)